# Looking for example of an order homomorphism that doesn't preserve joins.

Tags: examples-counterexamples, order-theory, lattice-orders

I know that not every order homomorphism preserves joins. But, I can't think of an example!

Both minimal examples and 'natural' examples welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $S$ be the poset

[image]

and let $T$ be the poset

[image]

Then the map $\phi:S\to T$ defined by
$$\phi(a)=y,\quad \phi(b)=z,\quad\phi(c)=w$$
is an order homomorphism, but
$$\phi(a\vee b)=\phi(c)=w\neq x=\phi(a)\vee\phi(b).$$

Comment: Very minimal, thank you!

Comment: Try dollar sign \hspace{7cm} dollar sign. For generating empty space to move stuff around.