# What's more robust than a structural homomorphisms?

Tags: category-theory, model-theory

*This question isn't category theory; but, category theoreticians tend to be interested in mathematical structure, so I thought the answer might exist within that knowledge base.*

Given two mathematical structures $X$ and $Y$ with the same pattern of airities, there is a natural notion of homomorphism $X \rightarrow Y$, described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_%28mathematical_logic%29#Homomorphisms_and_embeddings), called a structural homomorphism. However, this notion lacks "robustness."

For instance, suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are partially ordered sets and that $f$ is a structural homomorphism $f : X \rightarrow Y$. Then $f$ is an order homomorphism. Suppose also that $X$ and $Y$ happen to be lattices. Then we can add meets and joins to the data of $X$ and $Y$, thereby obtaining new structures $X'$ and $Y'$. However, its feasible that $f$ might fail to be a homomorphism $X' \rightarrow Y'$, since [not every order homomorphism is a lattice homomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394503/looking-for-example-of-an-order-homomorphism-that-doesnt-preserve-joins/394524?noredirect=1#394524).

So in general, if $f$ is a structural homomorphism $X \rightarrow Y$, and we extend $X$ and $Y$ by defining new relations/operations in terms of the old ones, thereby obtaining new structures $X'$ and $Y'$, well even if the new relations/operations are defined in terms of the old ones, using exactly the same definitions, nonetheless $f$ may fail to be a homomorphism $X' \rightarrow Y'$.

Now I originally thought that the notion of a "structural embedding" described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_%28mathematical_logic%29#Embeddings) in that same article, might be robust with respect to the defining of new relations/operations. But that's completely wrong.

So my question is, what's more robust than a structural homomorphism?

Comment: Note that the example by Zev is actually a structural embedding. If you want to have definable additions preserved then you probably need to require something like an elementary embedding.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, oh dear me you're right. Should I delete the question?

Comment: That's up to you.

Comment: @user18921 You can delete it of course if you wish to do so, but I believe it's actually a good question. You clearly spent time researching this, and even found the link which answers it ;-) Leaving it here might help others who stumble over the same problem, and will save them the time to find out for themselves.

Comment: You have observed that the notion of homomorphism depends on the category you are working in. That's right. Never forget that! And don't expect any universal or robust notion of homomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the example given by Zev in the previous thread is a structural embedding. So the same example shows that embedding between posets need not preserve meet/join.

For a stronger notion you should probably talk about theories as well, and require the embedding to preserve truth values of sentences, in the sense of an elementary embedding. Then you can extend definable operations from one structure to the next.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to get my head around the question: "how strong is the notion of an elementary embedding?" For instance, is every injective group homomorphism an elementary embedding?

Comment: This is equivalent to the question "Is every subgroup of a group $G$ an elementary submodel of $G$?" and the answer is no. But this notion is still stronger, and helps preserving a lot more information than structural embeddings or structural homomorphisms.