# Can every countable Boolean algebra be embedded into $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$?

Tags: order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

Can every countable Boolean algebra be embedded into $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$?

And if so, is the same true for countable semi-lattices?

Comment: Titles are titles, question bodies are question bodies.

Comment: I find the question a little unclear: in particular, what precisely do you mean by an embedding? In particular, do you want your embedding to preserve all the boolean algebra operations, or just the poset structure?

Comment: @goblin: The Boolean operators are definable from the order structure. You might want to ask if the embedding preserve arbitrary suprema and arbitrary infima, but a countable Boolean algebra is not a $\sigma$-algebra anyway.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, not quite getting it. It is of course not true that for all lattices $A$ and $B$, each order-embedding $f : A \rightarrow B$ preserves finite suprema. But perhaps if $A$ and $B$ are assumed to be Boolean algebras, then this suddenly becomes true?

Comment: @goblin: Your question, if so, was confusing me. The embedding maps the suprema to the suprema *in the range*. In any case, you can see from the definition of the embedding that it does in fact preserve suprema.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, okay. It seems that we're speaking a slightly different language, but I think I understand you now. I had [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394503/looking-for-example-of-an-order-homomorphism-that-doesnt-preserve-joins/394524?noredirect=1#394524) phenomenon in mind, but its true that if we take suprema "in the range" so to speak, then the issue is avoided.